# Reverse trailing into leading pad zeros in a sequence tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-transform

I have a sparse tensor (the tensor was generated using tf.Transform on a categorical value) which I convert it into a dense representation using the following command

```
bow_indecies = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sparse_bow_indecies, default_value=0)
```

which results in a matrix of size `batch_size x max_seq_length`. The array looks like this

```
[[ 597 1157   60    0    0    0]
 [ 939 1212  169   10    0    0]
 [ 242  719  215  520   57    6]]
```

I would like to reverse the zero padding from trailing to leading in order to look like this

```
[[   0    0    0   597  1157  60]
 [   0    0  939  1212   169  10]
 [ 242  719  215   520    57   6]]
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is one rude way to do that, if you can specify the indices of `SparseTesor`.

I mean you have to tell your `SparseTesor` object (`sparse_bow_indecies`) the indices of nonzero values.

The documentation says "Indices not in sp_input are assigned default_value."
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_tensor_to_dense

So in your case

May be the indices in your `SparseTesor` object (`sparse_bow_indecies`) should be some what like below for the result you are expecting.

```
SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 3], [0, 4],[0, 5],[1, 2],[1, 3],.....], values=[............], dense_shape=[3, 6])
```

or try overriding indices, if it the `SparseTensor` object is already with you.

```
sparse_bow_indecies.indices = =[[0, 3], [0, 4],[0, 5],[1, 2],[1, 3],.....] #Kept dots for continuation.
```

Comment: I don't define the sparse tensors. They are generated using tf.Transform by mapping the categorical values into integer indices.

Comment: I guess you can still modify the indices using "indices" property ... may be something like sparse_bow_indecies.indices = newsetofindices

Comment: Updated answer with other possible way. Give a try.